# Some Random characters appearing at beginning of .txt file after converting from base64 node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i am dropping a .txt file in an uploader which is converting it into base64 data like this:

```
 const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
        onDrop: async acceptedFiles => {
            let font = ''; // its not actually a font just reusing some code i'll change it later its a .txt file so wherever you see font assume its NOT a font.
            let reader = new FileReader();

            let filename = acceptedFiles[0].name.split(".")[0];
            console.log(filename);
            reader.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
            reader.onload = await function (){
                font = reader.result;
                console.log(font);
                dispatch({type:'SET_FILES',payload:font})
            };
            setFontSet(true);
        }
    });
```

Then a POST request is made to the node js server and I indeed receive the base64 value. I then proceed to convert it back into a .txt file by writing it into a file called signals.txt like this:

```
server.post('/putInDB',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    var bitmap = new Buffer(req.body.data, 'base64');
    let dirpath = `${process.cwd()}/signals.txt`;
   let signalPath = path.normalize(dirpath);
    connection.connect();
    fs.writeFile(signalPath, bitmap, async (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Successfully updated the file data');
//all the ending brackets and stuff
```

Now the thing is the orignal file looks like this :

> Time,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
>   0.000000,7.250553,14.951141,5.550423,2.850217,-1.050080,-3.050233,1.850141,2.850217,-3.150240,1.350103,-2.950225,1.150088

But the file when writing back from base64 looks like this :

> u«Zµìmþ™ZŠvÚ±î¸Time,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
>   0.000000,1.250095,0.250019,-4.150317,-0.350027,3.650278,1.950149,0.950072,-1.250095,-1.150088,-7.750591,-1.850141,-0.050004

See the weird characters in the beginning ? Why is this happening.

Comment: You converted it to a data URI, which has a base64 component to it but is not *all* base64. Try logging it. (Also, have you considered multipart/file-data instead? No 33%+ transfer overhead, supported natively by `FormData` without a separate reading step, no memory overhead, ….)

Comment: I don't see `useDropzone` doing any actual base64 conversion, what part of it makes you say that it's an "uploader which is converting it into base64 data"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the ```readDataAsUrl``` part

Comment: @Ry- that seems like a good idea can you point me to reference i can use to implement that thank you.

Comment: @Ry- what do you mean by not all base64?

Comment: @HadiPawar Okay, so what makes you think that converts a file to base64? (e.g. did you remember to read [the explanation of that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to make doubly sure it does what you _think_ it does? In particular, note that big yellow warning box)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans uh coz i logged it and then copied it to an online decoder and it gives the exact value that was in the file. i m not sure why you're doubting it isn't base64 . it is

Comment: I am trying to get you to **read the text** on the MDN page for the function you're using, which _very clearly warns you_ that you need to strip out the leading bit of text that tells URL parsers "this is a data-uri, using base64 encoding", but is itself not base64 text at all. You _need_ to remove that before you try to convert to real data, and your code doesn't. Double-checking how functions that you're using work is always one of the first steps in debugging.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are right yeah i replaced the values and now its working thanks alot

Comment: good, then I've posted you an answer.

Comment: Also note that `new Buffer(data, encoding)` is deprecated in Node: use `Buffer.from(data, encoding)` instead, as `new Buffer` will stop working soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to read up on what the functions you use do, because you're using [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) which does *not* give you the base64 encoded version of your data: it gives you Data-URL, and Data-URLs have a header prefix to tell URL parsers what kind of data this will be, and how to decode the data directly following the header.

To quote the MDN article:

> Note: The blob's `result` cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove `data:*/*;base64`, from the result.

If you don't, blindly converting the Data-URL from base64 to plain text will give you some nonsense data at the start:

```
> Buffer.from('data:*/*;base64', 'base64').toString('utf-8')
'u�Z���{�'
```

Which raises another point: you would have caught this with POST data validation, because the Data-URL that you sent contains characters that are not allowed in base64. POST validation is *always* a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't the exact code, but it is difficult to reproduce your problem with the code you provided. But the data you are sending needs to be a URL/URI encoded form.

So essentially:

```
encodeURI(base64data);
```

Encode URI is built into javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

**EDIT:**

I saw you used the function `readDataAsUrl()`, but try using the `encodeURI` function and then `readDataAsUrl()`.

Comment: No it turns out it actually was correctly decoding i just had forgot to remove the 'data/text base64;' part using regex you should change your answer to reflect that